# Include reST snippet in sphinx build

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am generating HTML documentation for a large python project in a two-pass approach - first generate rst files with `sphinx-apidoc` and then HTML files from rst and python files with `make html`.

**Is there a way to include (prepend, append) reST snippets into every rst file in `make html`?**

I'd like to configure reST snippets to enframe every generated rst file, e.g. to change settings for extensions.
So far I've only found templates for jinja, which I believe are too far down the pipeline.

Alternatively I could imagine adding those snippets by script to every generated rst file, but I suspect, there's a generic solution for this.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? A header and footer imply HTML output, where you would do that in Jinja2 and customizing a theme (SO has many posts on this already). But you also say you want to insert reST snippets, which implies you want to insert raw code examples.

Comment: I want to expand the rst files with some included reST source to control the behavior of an extension. I edited the question.

Comment: Would rst_prolog or rst_epilog work? http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config.html#confval-rst_epilog